# Zsh new terminal tab opens in Home folder instead of CWD if foreground process

Tags: terminal, osx-mavericks, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just started using `zsh` and I have the `terminalapp` and `git` plugins so that new terminal tabs open in the current working directory. However, if a process is running in the foreground (a server, vim, etc), new tabs open in the home directory.

How can I change this behavior?

I'm using Terminal.app on OSX Mavercks.

Comment: This is an OSX Terminal.app question. You should look at your Terminal.app configuration options.

Comment: I don't think this an OSX Terminal.app question because I can successfully open new tabs and they open to $CWD when I'm using the default bash shell. But I have tagged this question with terminal and osx as well.

Comment: Definitely an OSX Terminal.app question. The ability to open new tabs or windows in the same directory is a Terminal.app feature. The default OS X bash shell has special functionality (defined in /etc/bashrc) that uses undocumented Terminal.app-specific control codes to communicate the dir state back to it. But OS X doesn't set that up for zsh or other shells.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. I'm also using zsh and OMZ on Mavericks. If I cd somewhere and run `vim` or `top` and open a new tab, it opens in the directory I ran the program from. Are you still seeing this, and do you have a specific sequence of steps to reproduce it?

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior anymore. I think it might have been fixed with an update to zsh. Currently on 5.0.5. Not sure what version I was seeing the problem in.

Comment: I'd think the problem was more likely in `oh-my-zsh` or one of its themes, since it's a lot more unstable and is what actually produces the Terminal control code sequences. If one of the `preexec` hooks it sets in `lib/termsupport.zsh` or some themes was emitting current-dir escape sequences, that could have caused it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the "Startup" section at the Terminal preferences, "Same Working Directory".

See this blog post
http://russellfinn.com/2013/10/25/current-working-directory-restoration-in-mavericks-terminal-with-tcsh/

Most likely the value is getting cleared when you issue a new command and it is set again  after the command finishes. Try placing the escape sequence (from the linked blog post) at the precmd_functions hook (i.e. search the `zshall` manual page for `add-zsh-hook`).

PS: see this answer https://superuser.com/questions/313650/resume-zsh-terminal-os-x-lion